# How to view the sensitivity analysis of the objective function in ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio

Tags: analysis, cplex, objective-function

Here is my code below

```
     *********************************************/
dvar float+ x; /* daily quantity of t-shirts*/
dvar float+ y; /* daily quantity of shorts */


maximize 6*x + 10*y; /* maximize the daily profit from t-shirts and shorts*/

subject to{
20/60*x + 10/60*y <=176; /* cutting department labour constraint*/
20/60*x + 50/60*y <=400; /* sewing department labour constraint*/
10/60*x + 10/60*y <= 96; /* packaging department labour constraint*/
x >= 100; /* minimum daily demand for t-shirts*/
}
```

i want to find a range for unit profit where optimal solution doesn't change by finding the co-efficiency of objective function.
 thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See "Sensitivity Analysis" at documentation

IDE and OPL > Optimization Programming Language (OPL) > Language User’s Manual > The application areas > Applications of linear and integer programming > Linear programming

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6MYV_3.4.0/ilog.odms.ide.odme.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/ODME/_pubskel/ODME_pubskels/startall_ODME34_Eclipse1043.html